# how to rotate view when device orientation changes keeping the correct size of window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to support full device orientation in my iPad app which uses cocos2d.
To accomplish this I thought I'll return YES for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation like before when I was working on apps without cocos2d, but in this case my view doesn't resize properly. 
To show you with what I ended up, it's example picture.
[image: not resized view]

you can see that orientation is landscape but the view is still portrait.
Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to set the autosize property of your view. the quick way is to set it in the "size inspector".

Answer (score 1):

Add the following function and perform respective changes

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what kind of changes? modifying original willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method, I ended up with something like this:
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
            break;

Comment: @user1480741 Where do you add that code? Added it to AppDelegate.m and put a breakpoint on it, but the code was never reached.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the autosize property of your view. the quick way is to set it in the "size inspector"[image: size inspector]

Comment: unfortunately it's not the case when you are working with cocos2d template. I'm working with CCNodes not UIViews but thanks for answer